# Log off animation in Pac-man rom

Tags: nexus-4, boot-animation, pac-rom

How can i change the default log-off animation in my nexus4(PAC man ROM). I was able to change the boot animation in data folder but unable to find the logoff animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [How to Change Shutdown animation](http://www.phonebuff.com/2011/06/change-shutdown-animation-for-android)

As it says, you'll find the location of the animation is *"/system/media/video/shutdown"*

Comment: But i cannot find `/system` folder in my root

Comment: Is there not a video/shutdown folder structure just where your boot animation exists? Both of these are supposed to be at the same location. If not, I'm not sure where else to find the same, as I have not used the PACMan ROM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your device specifically, but the structure i have is a bootanimation.zip & SHUTanimation.zip 
[image: sutanim]